# Material ui - How would i add small triangle in the corner?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to get results such as this in my MUI Button -
http://jsfiddle.net/bcGdJ/3160/

I ended up with this, but it seems that both `before` and `after` css selectors doesn't work.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Notifications from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import "./box.css";

const styles = {
    color: 'purple',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    minWidth: '40px',
    minHeight: '40px',
    borderRadius: 1,
    position: "relative",
    "&:before,&:after": {
      content: '',
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      borderColor: "transparent",
      borderStyle: "solid"
    },
    "&:before": {
      borderWidth: "8px",
      borderLeftColor: "#efefef",
      borderBottomColor: "#efefef",
    },
     "&:after": {
      borderRadius: "3px",
      borderWidth: "5px",
      borderLeftColor: "#fff", /* color of the triangle */
      borderBottomColor: "#fff" /* color of the triangle */
    }
  };

function CustomizedInputs(props) {
  return (
    <div id="container">
      <Button color="primary" style={styles}>
        <Notifications />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomizedInputs;
```

```

https://codesandbox.io/s/72jyr75461

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nice but you missed some simple points.

You need to use `content: "''"` instead of `content: ""`.

You need to use `::` instead of `:` for `before` and `after`.

```
  cssRoot: {
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
    backgroundColor: purple[200],
    minWidth: "40px",
    minHeight: "40px",
    borderRadius: 1,
    position: "relative",
    "&::before,&::after": {
      content: "''",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      borderColor: "transparent",
      borderStyle: "solid"
    },
    "&::before": {
      borderWidth: "8px",
      borderLeftColor: "#efefef",
      borderBottomColor: "#efefef"
    },
    "&::after": {
      borderRadius: "3px",
      borderWidth: "5px",
      borderLeftColor: "#fffff" /* color of the triangle */,
      borderBottomColor: "#fffff" /* color of the triangle */
    }
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/541v247qlp